# How do I get access database to form a relationship from one to many?

Tags: database, ms-access

In my database I have formed the relationship from one to many on the right of the screen shot, but for some odd reason it will not let me do it on the left of the screenshot.  I want to connect both cust_IDs (or customer IDs) and make it a one to many relationship. I would really appreciate any help this because it will allow me to practise forming one to many relationships on Microsoft Access.

[Here is my screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQaSZ.png)

Comment: Each customer can rent many videos. Each video can be rented to many customers. This is many-to-many relationship. The tblRentals is a 'junction' table relating customers and videos. What do you mean by 'won't allow'? Did you double click on the link line to open relationship dialog to change the relationship type? You might want to take a look at Microsoft Lending Library database template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy in Access and will not require any code.

Create a main form based on tblCustomers.

Save this form.

Now create a multiple items form based on tableRentals.

Delete the column for vid_no, and then use the combo box wizard to create a combo box – this will allow you to select from tblVideo, and return/set the vid_no column.

Ok save this form.

Now re-open the main tblCust form in design mode, and drag + drop in the multiple items form you created above.

You should now have a working form.